# Kendoui grid: on row edit (custom button), I would like to pass all column values to new page

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created a edit button using template in last column of the row. when I click the edit button, I would like to submit all the column values to a page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my issue mentioned above.

with in the template, I have a hyperlink and onclick event I am calling function editRow

```
function editRow(){
var ds = jQuery("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
    var row = ds.select();
    var dataItem = ds.dataItem(row);
    var field1 = dataItem.field1; //where field1 is the field in columns parameter in grid
}
```

Hope this helps....